# MySQL: Compare two TABLES and list rows that are new?

Tags: php, mysql

We have a daily data feed. I need to determine what rows are new. (It's a long story, but there are no record numbers for the rows and they aren't going to be any.) We need to be able to identify which rows are new since the previous data feed. The file comes in as JSON and I have been putting it into a MySQL TABLE for other purposes.

How do I take yesterday's TABLE and compare it to today's TABLE, and to display those rows which have been added since yesterday? Can all this be done in MySQL, or do I need to do this with the help of PHP?

If I was doing this in PHP, I'm thinking I would search today's TABLE with yesterday's TABLE, and flag (an added column) in today's TABLE called NEW with a "N" when it's found. "Y" would be the default which means the row is new. Then using MySQL do a select where new="Y" and this would display the new fields. Is this how to do this? Am I overlooking a better method? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a timestamp column for when the rows were added?

Comment: if you have a time stored for the data when they are created you can just do time manipulation to achieve your goal..

Comment: There is no timestamp from the source, only the one I added when the data is downloaded from the daily feed.

Comment: What columns are there in both the tables?

Comment: Do you actually have two separate tables (one for today and one for yesterday)?

Comment: @hjpotter92 the columns in both tables are the same. They are part numbers with descriptions.

Comment: @Scotch Yes, two separate tables i.e. today_table and yesterday_table. Both tables have the same columns.

Comment: Please provide table schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually have two separate tables (which is how it sounds from your description, but is odd) and aren't comparing literally the same table, you can

```
  SELECT partnumber FROm Today_table where partnumber not in (select partnumber from Yesterday_table)
```

Comment: It's just one way to do it, you could also use a left join with a null condition or a `MINUS` (but not in MySQL)